# How to change name of months in UIDatePickerView in swift?

Tags: swift, date, uipickerview

I want to have DatePickerView but with some different . I want to change name of months for example instead of january I want "monthsOne" name . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UIPickerView` instead - it gives you full control over all titles for all rows.